# I tried to install MySQL Community, but it always install MySQL Commercial

Tags: mysql, windows, installation, mysql-8.0

When I write the follow code in cmd: `"C:\mysql-installer-community-8.0.12.0.msi /passive"`, the MySQL version were installed is the commercial, not the Community. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hi Fabio, so you have this file ("C:\mysql-installer-community-8.0.12.0.msi"), the name imply it is a community build, but can you tell us where you got this file ?  A link to the website where you downloaded this file could be useful to help you with this.

Comment: Link to public MySQL bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92600

Comment: @jfg956 Yes, I created it after the colleague's tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabio, here is the problem.

You have to execute the following statement to install MySQL Server Community version: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\MySQLInstaller.exe Community`

Answer (score 3):

Bill, this certainly looks like a bug, you are not doing anything wrong. You should raise a bug report at https://bugs.mysql.com for MySQL Installer.

Comment: Thanks, I created Link to public MySQL bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92600